# How to create n level nested expand/collapse component dynamically in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular5

I am developing a script of n-level of nested tables using div.

So there are 5 to 6 columns with `n` number of rows, every first column have to expand/collapse button, on click of which I make a call to API which gives me data respective to selected row filters.

Previously when I worked with core JavaScript and jQuery, I was using `find` method of document selector to identify the parent of expand/collapse button and push dynamically created HTML after that specific div only using `innerHTML` or `append` method of jQuery

I am a bit new to angular and haven't worked much. Please help me to solve this.

`splitOpt` is an array of objects based on which I will split report data.

```
this.splitOpt = [
    {
        id: "country",
        label: "Country"
    },
    {
        id:"os".
        label:"Operating System"
    },
    {
        id:"osv".
        label:"Operating System Version"
    }
]
```

Function to get reports

```
getReport() {

    // apiFilters are array of object having some values to filter report data  
    var apiFilters: any = [{}];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.sFilters.length; i++) {

        if (this.sFilters[i][0].values.length > 0) {
            var k;
            k = this.sFilters[i][0].id
            apiFilters[0][k] = this.sFilters[i][0].values;
        }
    }

    var split = this.splitOpt[0].id;
    this._apis.getReportData(split, apiFilters[0]).subscribe(response => {
        if (response.status == 1200) {
            this.reportData = response.data.split_by_data;
        }
    })
}
```

Function to check if there are more splits or not

```
checkIfHaveMoreSplits(c){
      if(this.splitOpt.length > 0) {
        var index = this.splitOpt.findIndex(function(v) {
          return v.id == c
        })

       if (typeof(this.splitOpt[index+1]) != "undefined"){
         return this.splitOpt[index+1];
       } else {
        return 0;
       }
   }

    }
```

Code to draw table based on split and report data.

Let's assume there is only one object for the country in `splitopt` object than `checkIfHaveMoreSplits()` returns `0` which means I do not have to give expand button and if it is not `0` that expand button will appear there.

Onclick of expanding button I will select next element from `splitopt` and call API to get report having split param as a carrier and so on.

```
<div class="table" >
<div class="row" *ngFor="let rData of reportData; let i = index;" >
        <div class="col" >

            <button 
                 class="btn btn-sm" 
                 *ngIf="checkIfHaveMoreSplits(splitbykey) !== 0"
                 (click)="splitData(splitbykey)"
                >+</button>
            {{rData[splitbykey]}}
        </div>
        <div class="col">{{rData.wins}}</div>
        <div class="col">{{rData.conversions}}</div>
        <div class="col">{{rData.cost}}</div>
        <div class="col">{{rData.bids}}</div>
        <div class="col">{{rData.impressions}}</div>
        <div class="col">{{rData.rev_payout}}</div>

</div>
```

I am managing one array which identifies how deep I can expand collapse element

Let us assume that array has three elements namely country, carrier, and os

So first table which I will draw having all the countries in the table with expand button on click of which I will send selected country and get carriers of that specific country. After getting the response I want to create custom HTML based on response and append html after selected row.

Here are the screenshots as well consist of full workflow :)

Step 1[image]

Step 2

[image]

Step 3

[image]

Comment: What is `splitbykey`

Comment: Split by key is single dimension value according to that our report data will be split.
for example.
At first user have selected country as split param so i will make call having split as country and api will provide response for all countries data and i will draw table accordingly, now suppose i want to get carriers data in that countries. next step will be selecting countries as split data. now next request will be like split parameter is carrier and specific country for which i will passed in filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd propose writing a custom angular component for each of your dynamic HTML pieces you want to display. Then you can write a recurrent component that will `*ngIf` your nested components based on a type list you provide. Like so:

```ts
// dynamic.component.ts

export type DynamicComponentType = 'country' | 'os' | 'osv';
export interface IOptions { /* whatever options you need for your components */ }
export type DynamicComponentOptions = { type: DynamicComponentType, options: IOptions};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamic',
  template = `
    <app-country *ngIf="current.type == 'country'" [options]="current.options" />
    <app-os *ngIf="current.type == 'os'" [options]="current.options" />
    <app-osv *ngIf="current.type == 'osv'" [options]="current.options" />
    <ng-container *ngIf="!!subTypes"> 
      <button (click)="dynamicSubComponentShow = !dynamicSubComponentShow" value="+" />
      <app-dynamic *ngIf="dynamicSubComponentShow" [options]="subOptions" />
    </ng-container>`,
  // other config
})
export class DynamicComponent {

  @Input() options: DynamicComponentOptions[];

  get current(): DynamicComponentOptions { 
    return this.options && this.options.length && this.options[0]; 
  }
  get subOptions(): DynamicComponentOptions[] {
    return this.options && this.options.length && this.options.slice(1);
  }

  dynamicSubComponentShow = false;

  // component logic, other inputs, whatever else you need to pass on to the specific components
}
```

Example for `CountryComponent`. The other components will look similar.

```ts
// country.component.ts

@Component({
  selector: 'app-country',
  template: `
    <div>Country label</div>
    <p>Any other HTML for the country component using the `data` observable i.e.</p>
    <span>x: {{ (data$ | async)?.x }}</span>
    <span>y: {{ (data$ | async)?.y }}</span>
  `,
})
export class CountryComponent {

  @Input() options: IOptions;

  data$: Observable<{x: string, y: number}>;

  constructor(private countryService: CountryService) {
    // load data specific for this country based on the input options
    // or use it directly if it already has all your data
    this.data$ = countryService.getCountryData(this.options);
  }
}
```

```ts
// my.component.ts

@Component({
  template: `
    <div class="table" >
      <div class="row" *ngFor="let rData of reportData$ | async; let i = index;" >
        <div class="col" >
          <app-dynamic [options]="options$ | async"></app-dynamic>
        </div>
        ...
      </div>
    </div>`,
  // other cmp config
})
export class MyComponent {

  options$: Observable<DynamicComponentOptions[]>;
  reportData$: Observable<ReportData>;

  constructor(private reportService: ReportService){

    // simplified version of your filter calculation
    let apiFilters: {} = this.sFilters
      .map(f => f[0])
      .filter(f => f && f.values && f.values.length)
      .reduce((f, acc) => acc[f.id] = f.values && acc, {});

    this.reportData$ = reportService.getReportData(this.splitOpt[0].id, apiFilters).pipe(
      filter(r => r.status == 1200),
      map(r => r.data.split_by_data)
    );
    this.options$ = this.reportData$.pipe(map(d => d.YOUR_OPTIONS));
  }
}
```

Now make your api return something like

```json
{
  "status": 1200,
  "data": {
    "YOUR_OPTIONS": [{
      "type": "country"
      "options" { "id": 1, ... } // options for your country component initialization
    }, {
      "type": "os",
      "options" { "id": 11, ... } // options for your os component initialization
    }, ...],
    // your other report data for the main grid
  }
}
```

Please, adjust this to your specific needs. You will have to manage passing of state through the component hierarchy for example (using component state, observable services, MobX, NgRx - pick your poison).

Hope this helps a little :-)

Comment: Sounds good to me but that country , carrier and os will not be fixed.

Comment: there will be n number of options from apis so basically what i do i maintain one array having all dimensions. based on that i want to manage expand collapse thing

Comment: If I understand correctly you have `n` types of stuff you want to display in the recurrent collapse component, each type has to have its own setup and depends on some data from an API, right? As I wrote in the answer, the data management is not touched in the example, since I have no clue what you want out of it. The solution is general enough for you to connect to any type of state management. Maybe if you show how you load the data and what the structure is I can understand better and help you some more :-)

Comment: yeah i have updated code as well. it will be visible for all once its approved

Comment: Please, take a look at the updated examples. I hope I understood what you try to accomplish :-)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response. really appreciate. but still i dont think to go this way let me show you things by sharing screenshots
May be i am not able to clearly explain my problem.
Nothing wrong at your end.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not putting the solution here as I do not know what you js code is. But you might want to consider using [ViewContainerRef](https://v5.angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef) to append elements dynamically. Hope this helps

Comment: @RipulChhabra that would be helpful

Comment: Let me modify few things, current code is used for production. will have to create demo like code. give me some moments i will update it

Comment: @JanakPrajapati I'm short on time so will not be able to give you the exact code. I'll post an answer later to this when I get time, in the mean time you can refer the demo that Angular has provided [here](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader). You can also download the [example](https://angular.io/generated/zips/dynamic-component-loader/dynamic-component-loader.zip) related to it. It is pretty self-explanatory if you are familiar with Angular.

Comment: Thanks i ll try to do it

Comment: i tried to implement same but did not worked out for me
I have basically created child component.
On click of expand button i load that dynamic child component and place it in row 
But problem is each time it is including in same container rather than respective of button click row
Here is code i have created another question just in case if you can help me with it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52535851/insert-dynamically-create-component-after-clicked-row