# Insert dynamically create component after clicked row

Tags: javascript, angular5, angular-components

I am working on solution in which i want to append dynamically created component after clicked row

I have table consist rows with action button on click of which i will call angular function and load component after that row.

Here is table code

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let rData of reportData; let i = index;" >
        <div class="col" >
            <button class="btn btn-sm" (click)="loadChildComponent()">+</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">Name</div>
        <div class="col">Description</div>
        <ng-template #dynamic></ng-template>

</div>
```

Code for dynamic components

```
Service.ts


import { DynamicComponent } from './dynamic.component'
@Injectable()
export class Service {
  factoryResolver;
  rootViewContainer; 
  constructor(@Inject(ComponentFactoryResolver) factoryResolver) {
    this.factoryResolver = factoryResolver
  }
  setRootViewContainerRef(viewContainerRef) {
    this.rootViewContainer = viewContainerRef
  }
  addDynamicComponent() {
    const factory = this.factoryResolver
                        .resolveComponentFactory(DynamicComponent)

    const component = factory
      .create(this.rootViewContainer.parentInjector)

    this.rootViewContainer.insert(component.hostView)
  }
}
```

Here is component file.

dynamic.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'
@Component({
  selector: 'dynamic-component',
  template: `<div class="row"  >
            <div class="col">Data</div>
            <div class="col">Data</div>
            <div class="col">Data</div>
            <div class="col">Data</div>
            <div class="col">Data</div>
            <div class="col">Data</div>
            <div class="col">Data</div>
    <ng-template #dynamic></ng-template>
    </div>`
})
export class DynamicComponent { }
```

Functions used to render dynamic component

```
@ViewChild('dynamic', { 
      read: ViewContainerRef 
    }) viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef

loadChildComponent() {
        this.service.setRootViewContainerRef(this.viewContainerRef)
        this.service.addDynamicComponent()
    }
```

Right now its appending in same div for any of rows

i would like to append it after clicked row

Please help..

Comment: From what I understand, you are able to get the dynamic template, but it is not displayed in a separate row, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ng-template` in Angular acts like a ghost element i.e. it is never displayed directly. Check this [link](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#the-ng-template).

**Update:**

You are having the template inserted with first row always because you have used [`@ViewChild`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild). @ViewChild looks for the first element in the template.

Try using [`@ViewChildren`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren) instead.

Refer the following changes:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let rData of reportData; let i = index;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col" >
            <button class="btn btn-sm" (click)="loadChildComponent(i)">+</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">Name</div>
        <div class="col">Description</div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <ng-template #dynamic></ng-template>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

JS changes:

```
@ViewChildren('dynamic', { read: ViewContainerRef }) viewContainerRef: QueryList<ViewContainerRef>

loadChildComponent(index) {
        this.service.setRootViewContainerRef(this.viewContainerRef.toArray()[index])
        this.service.addDynamicComponent()
    }
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I will try to implement it!

Comment: My problem was this component always append on same position rather than respective to clicked row

Comment: Nope this is not working again issue is newly loaded content appending on same place,
what i want to achieve is, lets assume there are 10 rows drawn based on report data
if i click on first row, dynamic component should be appear after first row and if i click on 8th row, again component should be appear after 8th row. right now it gets added on same place with no respect to clicked row

Comment: @RipulChhabra check the updated answer. I hope this will help.

Comment: yep worked for me with little change
@ViewChildren('dynamic', { read: ViewContainerRef }) viewContainerRef: QueryList<ViewContainerRef>

Comment: one more little question what if i want to pass object in that ng-template?
i tries passing [name]="abc" & name="abc" both are not working
i want to create that dynamic component based on inputs so i will basically take those attributes as parameter process it in dynamic.component.ts file and append it

Comment: Thanks for helping me out ! but ngcontext thing work on ng-template only, some how i figured out issue i passed variable in addDynamicComponent() function and in service i set component instance . it worked
Simple solution but i was running out of my mind since week, feel so dumb because a basic thing missed