# How dynamic create component inside clicked table cell

Tags: angular, angular13, angular14

some.component.html

```html
<table>
  <tr *ngfor="let row in table">
    <td *ngFor="let cell in row" (click)="onCellClick($event)">Cell Text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  template: '<div>My Component</div>',
})
export class MyComponent { }


@Component({
  selector: 'app-some',
  templateUrl: './some.component.html'
})
export class SomeComponent {
  public table = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]];

  constructor(
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef
  ) { }

  onCellClick(event: MouseEvent): void {
    const myComponent = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(MyComponent);
  }
}
```

This code adds MyComponent after `</table>`. But I need MyComponent to be created inside of the clicked table cell (inside `td`). How can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert dynamically create component after clicked row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52535851/insert-dynamically-create-component-after-clicked-row)

Comment: No. It similar, but it's still not what I need.

Comment: Please be clearer in your answers. How is it different from the expected behavior ?

Comment: The question there is about rows, and my question is about cells. And I think that adding ng-template to ALL cells is overkill. I hope there is some more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: This factory-less version only works if you have the same number of cells in every row (since we're using cellsPerRow to guess the index of the cell) :

Alright, first import everything we'll need :

```js
import {
       Component,
       OnInit,
       ViewContainerRef,
       QueryList,
       ViewChildren,
} from '@angular/core';
```

Add a ViewChildren decorator below your constructor to get all the cells elems :

```js
@ViewChildren('cellElem', { read: ViewContainerRef })cellsElemsList: QueryList<ViewContainerRef>;
```

Add a cellsPerRow constant :

```js
private cellPerRow = 3;
```

Then modify your onCellClick like so :

```js
onCellClick = (rowIdx, colIdx) => {
    const cellIdx = (rowIdx * this.cellPerRow) + colIdx;
    this.cellsElemsList
      .filter((el, idx) => idx === cellIdx)[0]
      .createComponent(TestComponent);
  };
```

Finally, change the HTML to pass the current cell's index to onCellClick() (and add the future component's container, #cellElem, inside your td elem)  :

```html
<div *ngFor="let row of rows; let rowIdx = index;">
    <td *ngFor="let cell of row; let colIdx = index" (click)="onCellClick(rowIdx, colIdx)">
        <div #cellElem></div>
        Click me
    </td>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a great solution! But ComponentFactoryResolver is depricated for Angular v13. Is it possible to implement something similar on modern version of Angular (v13-14)?

Comment: Welcome :) I've updated my answer with a Factory-less version